# Can I run my map application on phone using debug key?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-emulator

There are two types of certificates for using google Map services in andriod. One is debug and other is production. I have created the key by using debug keystore/certifcate. I have following questions :

1) I have created few emulators in eclipse, but when I try to run Map application, those emulators are not show in run option.

2) Can I run Map application on my Android phone by using key which was created with debug certificate ?

Answer (score 0):

For the question 2: yes. I run my application with Google Map v2 and I use my debug key to test it. But you have to record it on [the Google API console](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start?hl=fr#the_google_maps_api_key):

I never run the map api on an emulator...sorry...